# Boostrap 4 carousel-indicator shape

Tags: carousel

I always encounter error whenever I try to change Bootstrap 4 image carousel-indicator shape from rectangle to eclipse. How can I change carousel indicator shape to circle in Bootstrap 4

Answer (score 0):

Original css code for indicators:

```
.carousel-indicators li {
position: relative;
-webkit-box-flex: 0;
-ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
flex: 0 1 auto;
width: 30px;
height: 3px;
margin-right: 3px;
margin-left: 3px;
text-indent: -999px;
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
```

What you need to do, is change `height` and `width` as you want, but values have to be equal, and add

```
border-radius: 50%;
```

Here is the result: 
[image: result screenshot]